# Custom Badge color on TabItem

Tags: swiftui, badge

I need to change the color of a tabItem badge in SwiftUI.
I founded this pod
https://github.com/jogendra/BadgeHub

Is it possible to use with SwiftUI?

I have tabItems:

```swift
TabView(selection: $selection) {
    FeaturedView(users: filteredUsers, usersCount: filteredUsersCount)
        .tabItem {
            Image(selection == 0 ? "ic_searchFill" : "ic_search").renderingMode(.template)
        }
        .tag(0)
    LikesView(userViews: self.userViews, userLikes: self.userLikes)
        .tabItem {
            Image(selection == 1 ? "ic_heartFill" : "ic_heart").renderingMode(.template)
        }
        .badge(userLikesCount)
        .tag(1)
    ConversationsView(conversations: conversations)
        .tabItem {
            Image("ic_chat").renderingMode(.template)
        }
        .badge(conversationsCount)
        .tag(2)
    SettingsView(user: user)
        .tabItem {
            Image(selection == 3 ?  "ic_profileFill" : "ic_profile").renderingMode(.template)
        }
        .tag(3)
}
```

Comment: you are sharing a link of swiftui package, so yes you can use it with your swiftui. just make sure you follow all the instructions.  I also saw there is a color changing option in the package that you shared too.

Answer (score 6):

Actually we can configure SwiftUI badge color as well, via appearance.

[image: Demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
init() {
    UITabBarItem.appearance().badgeColor = .purple   // << here !!
}

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Color.green.overlay(Text("One"))
            .tabItem { Image(systemName: "car") }
            .badge(4)
// ...
```

Comment: I need to implement badges with gradient

Comment: also, two badges need  to have different gradients..

Comment: And where in question these restrictions were mentioned? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me for the standard Tab Bar (TabView) with SwiftUI. This works for iOS 15 and 16.

```
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = UIColor(Color.purple)
UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
```